# How to increment value in database every second

Tags: javascript, mongodb, meteor

I have objects in a mongodb database that have:

1. Max Population.
2. Population Increment (How much population should increase by every second).
3. Current Population.

Users will be changing the population through different methods, but I want to have some code on the server that is incrementing the object's current population by the object's population increment every second until the max population is reached.

Any idea on how I could implement this? I think I need a meteor interval with a $inc query, but I have no idea in which file I should put this and how I will access the object's max population and increment values inside the query.

Comment: Thats a bad idea. Save the time when you update the current population and when you need the actual value you can calculate the new current-population with the time difference.

Comment: I can't do that because users will be calling methods that decrease or increment the population and it's a multiplayer game so I need that value to be stored by the database.

Comment: No. Please. Its a __bad__ idea to update thousands of records every second, this will pretty much kill your performance. You can __always__ calculate and store a actual current-population _when you need it_ with this method. If you don't need it, don't touch it. Calculate it _when_ you need it.

Comment: Ok. But say users are looking at a map filled with different objects. And the population of those objects is displayed to them in the UI. They will be changing the populations through different methods, but I still want them to see the counter increasing when they aren't doing anything. How can I make this work with the storing the time method you recommend?

Comment: You can update the numbers with JavaScript every second.

Comment: Just make sure that you sync the client with server's time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Performance concerns aside (if the number of objects to be updated is small say), you can do this using [Meteor.setInterval](https://docs.meteor.com/api/timers.html#Meteor-setInterval)

```
import { Meteor } from 'meteor/meteor'
Meteor.setInterval(()=>{
  MyCollection.find({ $where: { "this.population < this.maximumPopulation" }}).forEach(doc => {
    MyCollection.update(doc._id,{ $inc: { population: doc.populationIncrement }});
  }
},1000);
```